# MySql - Create a table and select from it in the same procedure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I’m trying to execute this simple code as a procedure in MySql using the PHPMyAdmin

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jobs AS (SELECT
    *
FROM
    all_jobs
WHERE
        job_object_type LIKE 'jobName'
        OR
        job_object_type LIKE 'jobStatus');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    jobs
```

But I’m getting an `error (#1064)` because of my second SELECT query. I’m coming from MS-SQL and there the `SELECT` would be executed without any problems. How can I execute the `CREATE TABLE X` query and direct after that the `SELECT * FROM X` query in the same procedure?

EDIT: forgot to mention that I’m using the MariaDB

Comment: If you are getting an error like "check the manual for the correct syntax to use near 'SELECT` then it is because you did not terminate the `CREATE TABLE` statement with a `;`  MySQL expects statements to be delimited by `;` and depending on the client you are using, you may also need to surround the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement with a `DELIMITER` keyword to temporarily set a different one.

Comment: In particular, review the user examples at the bottom of the manual page for samples: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: I put the ";" at the end of my CREATE TABLE and I’m still getting the error

Comment: Please post your exact and complete `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement and the complete error message it produces. Also, are you using the mysql command line client? MySQL Workbench? PHPMyAdmin? The client used may affect how you have to craft the statement due to the delimiter issue.

Comment: I'm using the PHPMyAdmin to create the procedure and to edit it. The CREATE PROCEDURE in my question is the complete one.

Comment: The error massage is:  One or more errors have occurred while processing your request:
The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`() DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jobs AS (SELECT * FROM all_jobs WHERE job_object_type LIKE 'jobName' OR job_object_type LIKE 'jobStatus') SELECT * FROM Jobs"
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM Jobs' at line 10

Comment: Edit above to post the whole thing. Based on the error message, I do not see a `;` after `LIKE 'jobStatus')` and before the following `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Well that is how it's done using the PHPMyAdmin:

```
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jobs AS (SELECT
    *
FROM
    all_jobs
WHERE
        job_object_type LIKE 'jobName'
        OR
        job_object_type LIKE 'jobStatus');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    jobs;
END
```

Now everything is being executed as it should be.